# cdk drag and drop hover or mouseover not working

Tags: angular, firefox, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have implemented multiple drag and drop using cdk library on my Angular project(Version 10.2.5). The problem is (using firefox browser) when i drag something the hover effect of the drop container won’t take any effects anymore. With googlechrome my style works fine. I have tried already with @HostListener(‘document:mouseover’, [‘$event’]) but stills not working. It seems my mouse is disable when dragging an element.

I have this Problem since i updated to the Version 10 ,before everything works fine.

Comment: I imagine you can use the "events" cdkDragEntered/cdkDragReleased to give value to a variable and use some like `[style.background]="variable?'blue':null`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.